# Ordering a stacked histplot based on total counts

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataframe which results from:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['A'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame(df_grouped)
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df_grouped.index)
df_grouped.index = new_index
df_grouped.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_grouped.columns = ['A', 'B', 'count']
```

Then, `df_grouped` is something like:

| A | B | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_1 | B_1 | 10 |
| A_1 | B_2 | 51 |
| A_1 | B_3 | 25 |
| A_1 | B_4 | 12 |
| A_1 | B_5 | 2 |
| A_2 | B_1 | 19 |
| A_2 | B_3 | 5 |
| A_3 | B_5 | 18 |
| A_3 | B_4 | 33 |
| A_3 | B_5 | 44 |
| A_4 | B_1 | 29 |
| A_5 | B_2 | 32 |

I have plotted a `seaborn.histplot` using the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,5))
sns.histplot(x='A', hue='B', data=df_grouped, ax=ax, multiple='stack', weights='count')
```

and results in the following image:

[image]

What I would like is to order the plot based on the total counts of each value of A. I have tried different methods, but I am not able to get a successful result.

### Edit

I found a way to do what I wanted.

What I did, is to calculate the total counts by `df['A']` values:

```
df['total_count'] = df.groupby(by='A')['count'].transform('sum')
df = df.sort_values(by=['total_count'], ascending=False)
```

Then, by using the same plot code from above, I got the desired result.

The answer is similar to what Redox proposed.

In any case, I will try the other options proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To be clear, the visualization is a stacked bar chart, it's not a histogram, as a histrogram represents the distribution of continuous values, while this is the counts of discrete categorical values.
- This answer starts with the raw dataframe, not the dataframe created with `.groupby`.

1. The easiest way to do this is create a frequency table of the raw dataframe using [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), not with `.groupby`.
2. Add a column with the [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) along `axis=1`.
3. Use the new column to sort the dataframe.
4. Plot directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) using `kind='bar'` and `stacked=True`.

   - `seaborn.histplot` is not needed, and `seaborn` is just a high-level api for `matplotlib`
   - `pandas` uses `matplotlib` by default for plotting.

- This reduces the code to 4 lines.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import numpy as np  # used for creating sample data
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe representing raw data
np.random.seed(365)
rows = 1100
data = {'A': np.random.choice([f'A_{v}' for v in range(1, 6)], size=rows, p=[.35, .05, .25, .15, .2]),
        'B': np.random.choice([f'B_{v}' for v in range(1, 6)], size=rows, p=[.2, .35, .05, .15, .25])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# 1. frequency counts
dfc = pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B)

# 2. add total column
dfc['tot_A'] = dfc.sum(axis=1)

# 3. sort
dfc = dfc.sort_values('tot_A', axis=0, ascending=False)

# 4. plot the columns except `tot_A`
dfc.iloc[:, :-1].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(10, 5), rot=0, width=1, ec='k')
```

[image]

### Data Views

#### `df`

```
     A    B
0  A_5  B_5
1  A_3  B_1
2  A_4  B_5
3  A_3  B_4
4  A_3  B_5
```

#### `dfc`

```
B    B_1  B_2  B_3  B_4  B_5  tot_A
A                                  
A_1   86  131   15   55   90    377
A_3   47   90    9   33   61    240
A_5   37   83   13   33   56    222
A_4   43   65    9   27   50    194
A_2   16   21    1    5   24     67
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution works perfectly indeed. I just wanted to get an alternative with seaborn. In any case, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Kelo You're welcome, I'm glad this works for you. I was originally going to post an answer with .transform, but realized .crosstab was a more succinct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code... you need to get the order that you want the graph sorted (A_1, A_3, ...), then sort your dataframe `df_grouped` before plotting.

```
#Groupby A and sort by count - send the output as list to ord
my_ord = list(df_grouped.groupby(by=['A']).sum().sort_values('count', ascending = False).index)

# Order and sort the dataframe so that the final graph is also sorted
df_grouped['A'] = pd.Categorical(df_grouped['A'], categories=my_ord, ordered=True)
df_grouped = df_grouped.sort_values('A')

#Plot graph - no change here
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,5))
sns.histplot(x='A', hue='B', data=df_grouped, ax=ax, multiple='stack', weights='count')
```

**Output**

[image]